# Docker: How to use multistage images after build finishes

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-multi-stage-build

## Scenario

- Multistage builds combine multiple Dockerfile sections into a single one
- Intermediary and final stages can copy files from the upper stages
- Final stage is suggested to have only the binaries needed.

With those in mind, I'd like to build the follow

```
FROM fat-base as build
RUN setup unit test frameworks
RUN setup integration test frameworks
RUN setup functional test frameworks
RUN setup all heavy lifting stuff
CMD test

FROM slim-base
COPY --from=build /runtime/binary /bin/binary
ENTRYPOINT /bin/binary
```

## Reuse of Base Stage

- Instead of running tests in the intermediary stages, I'd like to run them outside the image so that I can re-order the sequence of tests and add more switches at a Pipeline layer (Jenkins CI, Travis, etc)
- I would like to be able to use the base image built.
- As suggested for Testing stages, a secondary `Dockerfile.test` could be used. However, I'd like to maintain a single Dockerfile with all stages.

Here's an requirement to run

```
docker build -t my-binary .
docker run -ti my-binary[0] unit
docker run -ti my-binary[0] integration --all
docker run -ti my-binary[0] functional --only-label=container
```

## Question

- Is this currently supported?
- Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained in [this page of the doc](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage), you can use the `--target` option of `docker build` to create an image corresponding to an intermediate stage of the build.

Using your `Dockerfile`, this would amount to the following commands:

```
docker build --target build -t my-binary-test .
docker build -t my-binary .
docker run -ti my-binary-test # run "test" as specified by "CMD test"
docker run -ti my-binary-test test unit
docker run -ti my-binary-test test integration --all
docker run -ti my-binary-test test functional --only-label=container
```

Note that I prepended the `test` program name in the last three commands above because the last instruction `CMD test` of your `build` stage will actually be overwritten by all the arguments given at command line. To have more insight on the semantics of `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` directives, I suggest to read [that section of the `Dockerfile reference`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

Also, you may want to use the `--rm` option of `docker run` in order to automatically remove the created containers when they exit.